# converting types from aws sdk v2 to v3 (typescript)

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am migrating a typescript codebase from aws sdk v2 to v3. In my code I have used several types from aws sdk v2 as follows:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
export async function uploadFn(
  s3: AWS.S3,
  ........
)
```

However, for types such as `AWS.S3` (and others) I can't find the equivalent type I should use in v3, and I've only been able to find the client/command equivalents of the functions I would normally call with an S3 object in aws sdk v2. Does anyone know if an equivalent type of `AWS.S3` (as in the code above) exists in v3, or should I change to type `any`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no v3 equivalent of the v2 `AWS` object.  The v3 SDK is [modular](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html#modularized-packages):

> The SDK is now split up across multiple packages. The 2.x version of the SDK contained support for every service.

The S3 client and commands, for instance, are packaged in [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html):

```js
import { S3Client, ListBucketsCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
```

The v3 packages have first-class Typescript support.